# How to extract first 30 characters from XML file?

Tags: xml

Could anybody please tell me how to extract the first 30 characters of the contents from XML file?

Comment: do you need the solution in pseudocode?

Answer (score 8):

Open the file in notepad, and select the first 30 characters.  Hit Ctrl-C.

If you want to do this programmatically, you'll need to tell us what language you're using.

Comment: I'm tired and I don't give a sh*t.  Ask a silly question - get a silly answer  :)

Comment: @ ApoY2k -  It's a little awkward. `did not have` is better.

Answer (score 1):

On linux/unix/cygwin:

```
head -c 30 myfile.xml
```

If you want the first 30 text characters outside of the tags then:

1) install [xmltwig](http://xmltwig.com/) - this is a perl module, so you will need to install perl if you do not have it.  Xmltwig includes the xml_grep utility.

2) run:

```
xml_grep --text_only myfile.xml | head -c 30
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, after reading the XML into an `XmlDocument`:

```
string s = doc.DocumentElement.InnerText.Substring(0, 30);
```

This returns the first 30 characters of the text nodes in the document, e.g.:

```
<foo>This is <bar>some sort of <baz>crazy</baz> markup.</bar></foo>
```

will return:

```
This is some sort of crazy mar
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file
Ask the file stream reader to read in first 30 bytes
Close the file

If you want the non-tag 30 characters, read the first 200 bytes, then run a regular expression to remove the tags.

Comment: reading the first 200 bytes doesn't work. It might very well contain only tags, leaving you with less than 30 characters ;^)

Comment: yeah yeah yeah. Ideally, get the first X chars, run the regex, if not enough, get more bytes.